# Cost effective Eclipse plugin license solution

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, licensing

I have an Eclipse plugin and want to release it. I want to add a license facility that limits the feature set depending on trial periods and annual renewals.  The only solutions that I have found are EasyLicenser, flexlm and JProductivity. Each of these cost a few thousand $ per year, this is well out of my price range. I am only asking 10's of $ per license and only expect 10's of customers. These license managers will cost more than I expect to make.

Are there any simple / cheaper solutions to the licensing of Eclipse plugins?

Comment: If you do a real cost analysis, you may find that the honor system plus a nag screen is very cost effective for low purchase price software.

Answer (score 1):

I found Padlock and am currently evaluating it using the trial download. The website states that there is a one off purchase price of $700 ... and an extended support if desired. I am sure it does not have all the features that the big boys offer ... but its more in my price range and without any heavy cracking, it locked me out without a valid license!

http://www.javalicensemanager.com/

Answer (score 0):

Could you just have a separate trial version and commercial version? If people want to buy the full version they then just install the new plug-in rather get a licence key or whatever.

If you're only talking about 10s of customers I wouldn't worry about stopping people copying the full version.

Comment: For reasons of maintaince on a separate product, in which I am "giving away" this Eclipse plugin, I need to incentivise users to purchase the annual maintainance license. If the Eclipse plugin license is only valid for a year, they are more likely to renew. (Well, that is the theory).

Comment: Yes, makes sense. I'm not sure you will find a licensing solution that is worth the hassle/cost though :(